# CSS animation breaks popup modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am clueless with an CSS problem and would appreciate any help.
I am creating a website for my local sports club and am not a full time code expert so the solution might also be obvious.
So far I ve created a mobile menu and now added some animations now. Adding the animations caused a the login modal that appeared onclick on "Login" not to work anymore.
Here is a code snippet showing the problem.
https://codepen.io/bvonr/pen/BaZvzPR

The problem is caused by the following code:

```
  .login {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99),
      opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  }
  .mobilenavigation .login {
    transition-delay: 0.21s;
  }
  .mobilenavigation.menu-opened .login {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.55s;
  }
```

If you remove lines 259 -272 from the codepens CSS, the animation for the login button doesnt work, if you keep them, the modal doesnt show up.

On the website I have barely any access to change the HTML so I am pretty much limited to CSS and JS
I would appreciate any help or idea.

Comment: When I look at the Codepen in Chrome on Windows 10, I can see the modal including the animation just fine. The same with that part of the CSS commented out. So can you include a snippet in your question that demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: The `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto` on the `.modal` seem to hide the content of the login modal. If you comment them out, you can see the modal. (Although not quite the way you might want it.)

Comment: Also, there are some errors in your javascript. Inside the `change.onclick` listener function, you're referencing `change` which is undefined inside that function. (Same problem may be on the other `onclick` listeners. Fixing that fixes the right class name setting. (And maybe the desired styling?)

Comment: I forgot to specify that I am talking about the mobilenavigation, sorry for that so above 1220px width everything works fine. 
For me in Chrome (on Mac) the modal is not showing up.

Comment: I also found that changing the overflow on the .modal changes the visibility. However I do not understand, why the appearance from the modal completely changes by adding the animations with transitions. and transform...

Comment: The javascript change.onclick also only refers to the mobilemenu. I assume you checked it in a setting with width > 1220px. 
Sorry, I should have specified before.